# Postgresql average interval between consecutive times--by day of week

Tags: postgresql, intervals, date-difference

I'm trying to get the average and median of the /difference of times/ along my timestamp variable to develop an expectation of whether data is "late" or not, relative to the previous timestamp.

That is--does the difference between now and the most recent timestamp exceed the average time interval between a timestamp and its previous for that day?  (More or less, I'm looking to create the lambda/mu term of an [arrival process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Occurrence_of_events) , and specifically, I'd like this mean/median to be sensitive to the day of week, as the [arrival process looks different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Inhomogeneous_Poisson_point_process) each DOW.)

My table looks like this:

```sql
create table Events (
  id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  datetime timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  );
  

insert into Events (datetime) VALUES 
('2021-03-28 00:00:00-06'),  -- say sunday is sparse, look it's every 8 hours-ISH, GIVE OR TAKE....
('2021-03-28 08:00:00-06'),
('2021-03-28 16:00:00-06'),
('2021-03-28 23:59:00-06'),

('2021-04-04 01:00:00-06'),
('2021-04-04 09:00:00-06'),
('2021-04-04 16:30:00-06'),

('2021-03-29 00:05:00-06'),  -- say monday is dense, look, it's approximately hourly
('2021-03-29 01:04:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 02:03:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 03:02:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 04:01:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 05:00:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 06:01:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 07:02:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 08:03:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 09:04:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 10:05:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 11:01:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 12:02:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 13:03:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 14:04:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 15:05:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 16:04:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 17:03:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 18:02:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 19:01:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 20:01:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 21:02:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 22:03:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 23:05:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 23:59:00-06'),


('2021-04-05 00:04:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 01:03:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 02:02:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 03:01:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 04:01:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 05:03:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 06:04:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 07:01:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 08:02:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 09:03:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 10:04:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 11:05:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 12:02:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 13:03:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 14:04:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 15:02:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 16:05:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 17:03:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 18:02:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 19:01:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 20:01:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 21:02:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 22:03:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 23:05:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 23:59:00-06'
);
```

My tentative query looks like this:

```sql
with subset as (
  select * from Events
  where extract (dow from datetime::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago'  = '0') -- subset on today is sunday
)
select 
  LAG(datetime,1) over (ORDER BY datetime) as lagged_interval,
  extract (epoch from AVG(LAG(datetime,1) over (ORDER BY datetime))) as average_interval_in_seconds,
  extract (epoch from percentile_cont(0.5) within group (LAG(datetime,1) over (ORDER BY datetime))) as median_interval_in_seconds,
  max(datetime) as most_recent
from subset;
```

You can see this [here in a db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wniHEVTCP8QkGGAr7qomgc/0).

Where I'm stumped is:

1. Is [LAG](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-lag-function/) the right operator to diff the timestamp versus the previous timestamp---this is a rowid kind of function?  A different or better window function?  The error I get right now is:

   Query Error: error: syntax error at or near "LAG"

But I'm a little puzzled by this since it looks right according to that doc.

2. How do I handle the first and last times in the day in the partition?  If I just do a subset to Sundays (with timezone shift) don't want the start for this week's Sunday to look back to the end of last week's Sunday, that would be too long, should I add a where clause to my outer `FROM` to exclude the first observation except for in the lag?

### UPDATE

I think this query is closer, it returns at least:

```
with subset as (
select * 
from Events
where extract (dow from datetime::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago')  = '0' -- subset on today is sunday
)
(select
  max(most_recent),
  AVG(ss.diff)/60 as avg_in_minutes,
  percentile_cont(0.5) 
    within group(order by ss.diff)/60 as q50_in_minutes,
  percentile_cont(0.05) 
    within group(order by ss.diff)/60 as q05_in_minutes,
  percentile_cont(0.95) 
    within group(order by ss.diff)/60 as q95_in_minutes
from (
  select 
  max(datetime) over (order by datetime) as most_recent,
  extract(epoch from datetime) as t1,
  extract(epoch from LAG(datetime,1) over (ORDER BY datetime)) as t0,
  extract(epoch from datetime) - extract(epoch from LAG(datetime,1) over (ORDER BY datetime)) as diff
  from subset
) as ss);
```

The results look good!

| max | avg_in_minutes | q50_in_minutes | q05_in_minutes | q95_in_minutes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-04T22:30:00.000Z | 2214 | 480 | 456 | 7439.999999999998 |

---

via: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/PqdiwBNnnKx3bUw1ALgt2/0

However, this query is a real mess!  Now it's unclear to me how I could partition over categorical variables in my subset to do this more generally.  For example if my starting table has a categorical variable:

```sql
create table Events (
  id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  datetime timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  category text default 'A'
  );
```

And I want these groups partitioned by category: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xr6JjG4KuuNVFLJCTof9UL/0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Schema (PostgreSQL v13)**

```
create table Events (
  id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  datetime timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  category text default 'A'
  );
  
 insert into Events (datetime, category) VALUES 
('2021-03-28 00:00:00-06', 'B'),
('2021-03-28 00:02:00-06', 'B');

  
insert into Events (datetime) VALUES 
('2021-03-28 00:00:00-06'),  -- say sunday is sparse, look it's every 8 hours-ISH, GIVE OR TAKE....
('2021-03-28 08:00:00-06'),
('2021-03-28 16:00:00-06'),
('2021-03-28 23:59:00-06'),

('2021-04-04 01:00:00-06'),
('2021-04-04 09:00:00-06'),
('2021-04-04 16:30:00-06'),

('2021-03-29 00:05:00-06'),  -- say monday is dense, look, it's hourly
('2021-03-29 01:04:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 02:03:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 03:02:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 04:01:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 05:00:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 06:01:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 07:02:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 08:03:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 09:04:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 10:05:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 11:01:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 12:02:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 13:03:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 14:04:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 15:05:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 16:04:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 17:03:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 18:02:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 19:01:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 20:01:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 21:02:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 22:03:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 23:05:00-06'),
('2021-03-29 23:59:00-06'),


('2021-04-05 00:04:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 01:03:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 02:02:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 03:01:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 04:01:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 05:03:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 06:04:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 07:01:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 08:02:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 09:03:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 10:04:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 11:05:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 12:02:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 13:03:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 14:04:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 15:02:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 16:05:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 17:03:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 18:02:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 19:01:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 20:01:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 21:02:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 22:03:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 23:05:00-06'),
('2021-04-05 23:59:00-06'
);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
with subset as (
select * 
from Events
where extract (dow from datetime::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago')  = '0' 
)
(select 
  category,
  max(most_recent),
  AVG(ss.diff)/60 as avg_in_minutes,
  percentile_cont(0.5) 
    within group(order by ss.diff)/60 as q50_in_minutes,
  percentile_cont(0.05) 
    within group(order by ss.diff)/60 as q05_in_minutes,
  percentile_cont(0.95) 
    within group(order by ss.diff)/60 as q95_in_minutes
from (
  select 
  category,
  max(datetime) over (partition by category order by datetime) as most_recent,
  extract(epoch from datetime) as t1,
  extract(epoch from LAG(datetime,1) over (ORDER BY datetime)) as t0,
  extract(epoch from datetime) - extract(epoch from LAG(datetime,1) over (ORDER BY datetime)) as diff
  from subset
) as ss
group by category);
```

| category | max | avg_in_minutes | q50_in_minutes | q05_in_minutes | q95_in_minutes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-04-04T22:30:00.000Z | 1844.6666666666667 | 479 | 112.5 | 7005 |
| B | 2021-03-28T06:02:00.000Z | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4F95CjPQFP5wtrR5nt4DqK/0)

Comment: This is incorrect because of the gap between weeks.

Comment: You need to aggregate by days specifically